# Cannot find jQuery tools "overlay" when I try to register it more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, overlay, jquery-tools

jQuery tool's overlay is a good webhelper to show div. Normally, we are recommended to register the overlay in the jquery ready function. And it works well at my side.

Now I want to register the overlay on the fly. I mean:

1. I create a div on the fly which will be used to load my content .
2. Then I use the newly created div to register the overlay.
3. last thing is triggering the event.

Below is my sample code:

```
<pre><code>

function RegisterOverlay(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).overlay({
        mask: {
            color: '#789',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.7
        },
        load: true,
        onBeforeLoad: function () {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.width = overlayConf.width;
            document.getElementById(divId).style.height = overlayConf.height;
            this.getConf().top = overlayConf.top;
            this.getConf().oneInstance = true; //overlayConf.oneInstance;
            this.getConf().closeOnClick = overlayConf.closeOnClick;
            this.getConf().closeOnEsc = overlayConf.closeOnEsc;
            this.getConf().top = overlayConf.top;
            this.getConf().effect = overlayConf.effect;
            this.getConf().fixed = overlayConf.fixed;
            this.getConf().speed = overlayConf.speed;
            this.getConf().mask.color = overlayConf.Mask.color;
            this.getConf().mask.loadSpeed = overlayConf.Mask.loadSpeed;
            this.getConf().mask.opacity = overlayConf.Mask.opacity;
            this.getConf().mask.colseOnEsc = overlayConf.Mask.colseOnEsc;
            this.getConf().mask.colseOnClick = overlayConf.Mask.colseOnClick;
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(overlayConf.url);
        },
        onClose: function () {
            var overlayAll = document.getElementById("overlayAll");
            overlayAll.removeChild(document.getElementById(divId));
        }
    });
}

 function ParentOverlay(conf, divId) {
    overlayConf = conf;
    CreateDiv(divId);//create a div based on a given id
    RegisterOverlay(divId);//
}
```

The above code is hosted on a parent page, so every child page can call the ParentOverlay function with some parameters. Sorry for my poor english, the child page is hosted in a iframe. Does the frame cause the following issue?

My question:

There is a very child page, where I have three buttons. Clicking any of them will trigger the ParentOverlay with different paras.

After the page is successfully loaded, I click the first button, everything is AOK as expected, I close the overlay, but after that when I try to click one of three buttons again. the error comes:

**Object doesn't support property or method 'overlay'**

This happens where I try to register the overlay:

**$("#" + divId).overlay(...**

Btw. there is nothing wrong with the buttons and this has nothing to do with the order of my clicking the buttons.

It is simple: first click is ok. then all suck.

I debuged this, I found if I just hard code the three divs for the three buttons and register the three overlays in the jquery ready function. all are ok no matter how many times I click the buttons. But this is a urgly solution that I cannot acccept. I wanna make it on the fly and reuse the code.

I also tried to set the load property to false. and it makes no sense.

Now, I really don't know how and what to do. Maybe there are some special settings but that I still don't know yet.

Can anybody here share me some experiences of give me a little clue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw overlayConf is a global variable which is a js object and contains some value for the overlay. I don't think this has something to do with my isue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. There is nothing wrong with the overlay or jQuery. But I made a stupid mistake that I load the jquery.js two times and this makes mechanism of jquery's extend function failed.

Then when $("#" + divId).overlay(), error comes:Object doesn't support property or method 'overlay'